# Trying to make my Fix nav bar with containt on the left, a white box and it doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

Please I need some help. I'm a noobie in programming and I'm trying to solve this problem.

I am trying to make a nav bar with the letter in hex color #66CD00, positioned to the right and fixed. With a white block around it that follows together with the navbar. But When I try to do this either the background-color white doesn't cover the whole nav bar, or the "home, works, about" section end up going to the left and doesn't stick to the position I want; In the right.

Another problem is that My "Home, Works, About" part, as I scroll down the page, gets behind some of the pictures I put. So if anyone can help me with that too I would appreciate very much.

Sorry to ask so much. But I tried hard and just got stuck.

Can someone please help me solve this puzzle? I know it seems silly, but I haven't found the exact answer to that anywhere. Thanks for any help. Code and link to my codepen follows below.

link to code pen: https://codepen.io/JT_Cerqueira/full/YxOLxg/ (to visualize the code just click to change view to editor view.)

CSS and HTML

```css
/*==== the nav bar css goes below ==== */

.container {
  margin: 0;
  width: 80%;
}

header {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

header::after {content: '';
               display: table;
               clear: both;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  right: 7%;
  top: 0;
}

nav ul {margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
}

nav li {display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 70px;
        padding-top: 50px;
        position: relative;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #66CD00;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #78AB46;
}

nav a::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #444;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: o;
  width: 0%;
  
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
  
}

nav a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <div class="container">
    <nav> 
      <ul>
        <li><a href ="#home">Home<a></li>
        <li><a href ="#works">Works<a></li>
        <li><a href ="#about">About<a></li>
      </ul> 
    </nav>
  </div>  
 </header>
```

Also if anyone is willing to contribute in any means I am willing to remake my navbar or look for other sources and start from scratch.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change these two classes

`

```
.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
nav {
  position: fixed;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  background-color:white;
  z-index:99;
}
```

`

Comment: Thank you very much I will try that.

Comment: It worked perfectly, but there were a few issues. My Home, Works and About automatically went to the left again. Do you know how can I keep that effect and make it go to the right? Also for some weird reason is the white background is not covering the whole page. I save your code so you could see it how it looks. I liked it very much though and I appreciate the help. It helped me a lot. But do you know how can the background cover 100% of the page and my Home, Works and About go to the right? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Rohit I appreciate your help so much, that I'm even embaressed to ask more, but here I go. I had put float right, but I guess on the wrong part of the css and wasn't going right, but now it did. Thank you very much. But now I'm trying to control how far to the right it will go. I put right: 15px; and other px and isn't working. Also my background from the navbar continues to not cover the whole page :( .  Hope you can help me with this puzzle XD.  I'm feeling pretty stupid already.  got the whole thing done, but this navbar is getting on my nervers lol. Thanks.